# Загрузить файлы в /files при установке Андроид-приложения

Tags: java, android

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу при создании приложения на java. Как сделать, чтобы при установке приложения в папку files загружались определенные файлы? Сами файлы желательно упаковать в apk

Comment: уточните пожалуйста задача, покажите как вы пробовали ее решить и какие результаты ваших попыток, на текущий момент весьма сложно сказать что-то определенное

Comment: Собственно, пока никак.. Есть файлы, пробовал размещать их в разных директориях проекта, но пори установке скомпилированного приложения их нигде нет. Понимаю, есть вариант программно создать файлы при первом запуске приложения или создавать по мере необходимости и проверять, есть ли файлы и при наличии не создавать. Но это добавит дополнительный код и нагрузит систему. Идеальный вариант - один раз загрузить эти файлы непосредственно при установке приложения и забыть об этом. Никакой подходящей документации не нашел

Comment: При установке ничего сделать нельзя, ибо это была бы дыра для зловредов. К тому же файлы могут быть удалены в любое время, так что проверять их существование всё равно придётся и писать код для их восстановления тоже.

Comment: Посмотрите этот вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66602910/5479247